# Image Carousel not working although copied the js and css scripts

Tags: bootstrap-4

I copied the carousel code from the bootstrap website and have added 3 images to the carousel but it is not working. Only the 1st image is displaying. I have pasted the copied the js, css, jquery and cdn scripts from the bootstrap website too. I don't understand what the problem is ?

```
<!-- Carousel -->
<div id="carouselExampleIndicators" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="2"></li>
  </ol>
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="carousel-item active">
        <img class = "d-block w-100" src="img/carousel_1.jpg" class="d-block w-100" alt="First Image">
        <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
          <h1>First slide label</h1>
          <p>Nulla vitae elit libero, a pharetra augue mollis interdum.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="carousel-item">
        <img class = "d-block w-100" src="img/carousel_2.jpg" class="d-block w-100" alt="Second Image">
        <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
          <h1>Second slide label</h1>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="carousel-item">
        <img class = "d-block w-100" src="img/carousel_3.jpg" class="d-block w-100" alt="Third Image">
        <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
          <h1>Third slide label</h1>
          <p>Praesent commodo cursus magna, vel scelerisque nisl consectetur.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
  </div>

  <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
  </a>
  <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="next">
    <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
  </a>
</div>


<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```html
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="example">
    <div id="carouselExampleCaptions" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
      <ol class="carousel-indicators">
        <li data-target="#carouselExampleCaptions" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
        <li data-target="#carouselExampleCaptions" data-slide-to="1"></li>
        <li data-target="#carouselExampleCaptions" data-slide-to="2"></li>
      </ol>
      <div class="carousel-inner">
        <div class="carousel-item active">
          <img src="mg/carousel_1.jpg" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
          <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
            <h5>First slide label</h5>
            <p>Nulla vitae elit libero, a pharetra augue mollis interdum.</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-item">
          <img src="..." class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
          <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
            <h5>Second slide label</h5>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-item">
          <img src="..." class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
          <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
            <h5>Third slide label</h5>
            <p>Praesent commodo cursus magna, vel scelerisque nisl consectetur.</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleCaptions" role="button" data-slide="prev">
        <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
      </a>
      <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleCaptions" role="button" data-slide="next">
        <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

You need to keep the 'link' tag inside 'head' tag